# XML wrapped collection not deserializing

Tags: c#, .net, xml, deserialization

I have some XML in the following format:

```
<PurchaseItem>
    <Name>Item 1</Name>
    <Costs>
        <Cost>
            <Code>A</Code>
            <Info>Test 1</Info>
        </Cost>
        <Cost>
            <Code>B</Code>
            <Info>Test 1</Info>
        </Cost>
        <Cost>
            <Code>C</Code>
            <Info>Test 1</Info>
        </Cost>
    </Costs>
</PurchaseItem>
```

I want this XML to deserialize into the following class:

```
public class PurchaseItem
{
    [XmlElement("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Costs")]
    public Cost[] Costs { get; set; } 
}

public class Cost
{
    [XmlElement("Code")]
    public string Code{ get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Info")]
    public string Info{ get; set; }
}
```

However I cannot seem to get this to work unless I make another class to be a wrapper for the `Cost[]`.
How can I have the cost array be serialized in the `PurchaseItem` class as in the code above?

Comment: Thanks, both Patrick and Daniel answers are right!

Comment: Bonus question: if i was to change the <Code> xml array element name in the xml to <FooCost> how can I specify that change in the c# class? (is it an attribute on the `Cost` class)

Comment: `[XmlArray(ElementName = "FooCosts")]
 [XmlArrayItem(ElementName="FooCost")]
 public Cost[] Costs { get; set; }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are defining an array, you should use the `[XmlArray]` attribute :)

```
[Serializable]
public class Cost
{
    [XmlElement("Code")]
    public string Code { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Info")]
    public string Info { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class PurchaseItem
{
    [XmlElement("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // XmlArray of Cost
    [XmlArray(ElementName = "Costs")]
    public Cost[] Costs { get; set; }
}

public class Tests
{

    [Test]
    public void Test()
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof (PurchaseItem));

        var xml = @"<PurchaseItem>
                        <Name>Item 1</Name>
                        <Costs>
                            <Cost>
                                <Code>A</Code>
                                <Info>Test 1</Info>
                            </Cost>
                            <Cost>
                                <Code>B</Code>
                                <Info>Test 1</Info>
                            </Cost>
                            <Cost>
                                <Code>C</Code>
                                <Info>Test 1</Info>
                            </Cost>
                        </Costs>
                    </PurchaseItem>";

        var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml);
        var reader = XmlReader.Create(new MemoryStream(data));
        var item = (PurchaseItem) serializer.Deserialize(reader);

        Assert.AreEqual(item.Costs[0].Code, "A");
        Assert.AreEqual(item.Costs[1].Code, "B");
        Assert.AreEqual(item.Costs[2].Code, "C");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because you have set the attribute `[XmlElement]` on the Costs array. In any case you should use the attribute `[XmlArray]` with an array or collection element. That lets you change for example the name of the collection element in the generated XML. (More info about the [XmlArray attribute here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributes.xmlarray.aspx))

However, the serializer provides the functionality you were looking for without the need of any attribute. Having this class:

```
public class PurchaseItem
{
    [XmlElement("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Cost[] Costs { get; set; }
}
```

Will get you the following Xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<PurchaseItem xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Name>Foo</Name>
  <Costs>
    <Cost>
      <Code>C#</Code>
      <Info>Awesome</Info>
    </Cost>
    <Cost>
      <Code>VB6</Code>
      <Info>:(</Info>
    </Cost>
  </Costs>
</PurchaseItem>
```

Only if you want to change how that collection is generated would you need to add an `[XmlArray]` attribute. For example if you want the node holding the costs elements to be named "FooCosts" then you need:

```
public class PurchaseItem
{
    [XmlElement("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlArray("FooCosts")]
    public Cost[] Costs { get; set; }
}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<PurchaseItem xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Name>Foo</Name>
  <FooCosts>
    <Cost>
      <Code>C#</Code>
      <Info>Awesome</Info>
    </Cost>
    <Cost>
      <Code>VB6</Code>
      <Info>:(</Info>
    </Cost>
  </FooCosts>
</PurchaseItem>
```